# How to customize list item images separately in css

Tags: css, image, list

I am trying to customize my ul li images separately using css but it just isn't working for me. I have tried putting id's on my images and putting classes on my li's but every time I do anything of the sort and try to do something to only one image, it does it to all of them.

Here is my html:

```
<div id="list">
<ul><li class="port"><a href="#"><img src="images/port.png" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="secrets"><a href="#"><img src="images/secrets.png" alt=""></a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="#"><img src="images/contact.png" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

And my css:

```
#list li.contact img { margin-top: -2em; }
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Based on the markup you supply, that rule will only apply to the image in the contact li. Perhaps some other CSS rule is affecting the other images? If you use Firebug and inspect the images which are being styled incorrectly, you should be able to see which CSS rule is doing it.

Comment: can you put your code on jsfiddle. because its working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/sachinyadav/dZ953/

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
#list{/*some css*/}
.class > image{/* css regarding image here */}


<div id ="list">
    <ul>
        <li class="port"><a href="stuff"><img src="stuff"></a></li>
```

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was because I had it display: inline, therefore I couldn't move one without the others moving, duh! Is there an easy way to make them display inline while still being able to lower one?